# SF Symbols 3.0: Use Restrictions

Tags: app-store-connect, development, developer-program

There is an icon I'd like to use, that has Use Restrictions.

The warning says:

> This symbol may not be modified and may only be used to refer to
> Apple’s Messages app.

This is fine, as my app will only use it in reference to its integration feature with the iOS Messages app.

But there is no option to use or export it? Am I unable to use it at all or am I missing something?

Comment: What were you thinking of using it for?

Comment: Do you want to know how to use a SF Symbol in an app? If so, please search on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com), the details vary whether you're using UIKit or SwiftUI.

Comment: No, I know how to use an SF Symbol. Just didn't understand the process of using a licensed one that's available to view in SF Symbols 3.0, but not available to use. @bmike answered my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple documents the license here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/ and https://developer.apple.com/terms/

> **IMPORTANT**
> All SF Symbols shall be considered to be system-provided images as defined in the [Xcode and Apple SDKs license agreements](https://developer.apple.com/terms/) and are subject to the terms and conditions set forth therein. You may not use SF Symbols — or glyphs that are substantially or confusingly similar — in your app icons, logos, or any other trademark-related use. Apple reserves the right to review and, in its sole discretion, require modification or discontinuance of use of any Symbol used in violation of the foregoing restrictions, and you agree to promptly comply with any such request.

You should be licensed “solely for the purpose of developing Applications for Apple-branded products that run on the system for which the image was provided.” per section 2.13 of https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/xcode.pdf as long as you meet all the other license requirements that you already agreed to.